# separating out a wcf service, server, and client

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a solution in VS 2010: a WCF Service Library project ("NotifyService") and two Windows Forms projects, one for a server ("NotifyServer")and one for a client ("NotifyClient"). My goal is to have a duplex WCF service that will notify any number of connected clients when the server pushes out a notification. The clients do not need to communicate to the server except to subscribe and unsubscribe from the server's updates. However I seem to be running into problems nailing down the InstanceContext.

Here's the code for the WCF service:

```
<ServiceContract(
    CallbackContract:=GetType(INotifyCallback),
    SessionMode:=SessionMode.Required)>
Public Interface INotifyService
    <OperationContract()>
    Sub Notify(ByVal what As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub Subscribe()

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub Unsubscribe()

End Interface

Public Interface INotifyCallback
    <OperationContract(IsOneWay:=True)>
    Sub OnNotify(ByVal what As String)
End Interface

<ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)>
Public Class NotifyService
    Implements INotifyService

    Private _callbacks As New List(Of INotifyCallback)

    Public Sub Notify(ByVal what As String) Implements INotifyService.Notify
        For Each callback As INotifyCallback In _callbacks
            callback.OnNotify(what)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Subscribe() Implements INotifyService.Subscribe
        Dim client As INotifyCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel(Of INotifyCallback)()
        If Not _callbacks.Contains(client) Then
            _callbacks.Add(client)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Unsubscribe() Implements INotifyService.Unsubscribe
        Dim client As INotifyCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel(Of INotifyCallback)()
        If _callbacks.Contains(client) Then
            _callbacks.Remove(client)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Server form has a reference to the DLL created by the service library and self-hosts an instance of the WCF server in code:

```
Public Class frmServer
    Private _host As ServiceHost
    Private _notifier As NotifyService.NotifyService

    Public Sub go() Handles Me.Load
        _host = New ServiceHost(GetType(NotifyService.NotifyService), New Uri("net.tcp://localhost:10000"))
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(NotifyService.INotifyService), New NetTcpBinding, "NotifyService")
        _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(New ServiceMetadataBehavior)
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding, "mex")
        _host.Open()
        _notifier = New NotifyService.NotifyService
    End Sub

    Private Sub send() Handles Button1.Click
        _notifier.Notify("Foo")
    End Sub
End Class
```

For the most part that all seems to work. I can use the WcfTestClient to connect and it at least sees the services, though since it's a net.tcp binding with duplex enabled I can't actually test it using that client.

When I created the client I added a service reference called NotifyGateway. Here's the client form code:

```
<CallbackBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    UseSynchronizationContext:=False)>
Public Class frmClient
    Implements NotifyGateway.INotifyServiceCallback

    Private _service As NotifyGateway.NotifyServiceClient = Nothing

    Public Sub OnNotify(ByVal what As String) Implements NotifyGateway.INotifyServiceCallback.OnNotify
        MsgBox(what)
    End Sub

    Public Sub go() Handles Button1.Click
        _service = New NotifyGateway.NotifyServiceClient(New InstanceContext(Me), New NetTcpBinding, New EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:10000/NotifyService"))
        _service.Open()
        _service.Subscribe()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Since I'm setting everything up through code, there are no app.config files. The problem I'm having is that my Subscribe method is never called. When debugging, I get an error after stepping through that line (not an exception) that says "Unable to automatically step into the server. The debugger failed to stop in the server process." When I go back to my server form and click the button designed to raise an event on the callback clients, it steps into the NotifyService class but the `_callbacks` list is empty, meaning the Subscribe method either never ran, or it never ran on that instance.

I have fought with this for almost a week. This is nearly an identical copy, at least on the service-side, to what was described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_Duplex_UI_Threads.aspx), and I've compiled that and it works. So I'm a little lost as to where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall` on your service. This means that a new instance of your service is created every time a method is invoked. So when you call `_notifier.Notify("Foo")`, it creates a new instance of your service class, which means it doesn't have any subscribers. There are a few ways you can approach this:

- One way would be to set `InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single`, which means there will be a single instance of your service class which will handle all requests for the lifetime of your service. Together with your other setting of `ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Single`, this can be a bottleneck if you expect your service to be used heavily, since only one request will ever be processed at a time. You can change it to `ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, but then you'll have to be responsible for handling thread-safety inside your class, since that allows the single instance of your class to handle multiple requests at the same time.
- Another approach would be to change your `_callbacks` collection to be a static (Shared in VB.NET) member. That way your list of subscribers would be the same across all instances of your service class. In this approach, you would again be responsible for handling thread-safety concerns, since there will be multiple instances of your service class potentially accessing the single collection at the same time from different threads.
- You could use some type of persistence mechanism, such as a database. This would be the most involved, since you would basically have to re-construct a new proxy to each subscriber for each notification, but has the advantage of not losing all your subscribers if your application is shut down. That sounds like it's probably not the best fit for your situation.

Comment: Bullet point 2 did it. Done in by my own lack of paying attention to the C# to VB conversion. This won't be in much use - just a handful of computers, max, and all on the same network, so (don't cringe) I'm not too worried about thread safety. Shared members will work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'd go with `InstanceContextMode.Single`/`ConcurrencyMode.Single` then. It would only slow things down if you get multiple requests at the same time, and that's when you're going to have concurrency issues.